# Can the function getSymbols() take a variable instead of the ticker itself?

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to loop through a CSV of some companies tickers and download their respective ticker data.

So far I have defined the variable 'ticker' as follows:

```
ticker <- companyList[1, 'Symbol']
```

when I print 'ticker' to the screen, it shows the 1st stocks ticker perfectly fine, but when I try to pass the ticker variable into quantmod's getSymbols function, I get an error.

```
getSymbols(ticker)
Error in do.call(paste("getSymbols.", symbol.source, sep = ""), list(Symbols =   current.symbols;  : 
 could not find function "getSymbols.940"
```

Is there an error in my syntax? Is there another way to go about doing this? Any book reccomendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to specify an environment, for example assuming you have an vector with tickers, than you can do the following:

```
# tickers example
tik <- c("MMM", "ABT", "ABBV", "ANF", "ACT")

# new environment
stockData <- new.env() 

# download data
getSymbols(tik, env = stockData)
```

Than you can index to access the stocks: eg:

```
stockData$MMM

           MMM.Open MMM.High MMM.Low MMM.Close MMM.Volume MMM.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03    77.53    78.85   77.38     78.26    3781500        65.42
# 2007-01-04    78.40    78.41   77.45     77.95    2968400        65.16
# 2007-01-05    77.89    77.90   77.01     77.42    2765200        64.72
# 2007-01-08    77.42    78.04   76.97     77.59    2434500        64.86
# 2007-01-09    78.00    78.23   77.44     77.68    1896800        64.93
# 2007-01-10    77.31    77.96   77.04     77.85    1787500        65.07
```

same for all other stocks.

See also here: [Quantmod](http://gekkoquant.com/2012/05/13/quantmod-basics-stock-data-download-and-manipulation/)

hth

**EDIT**:

for exporting you can use something like this:

```
# this will export 
lapply(stockData, function(x){
  write.csv(x, file=paste0(gsub(".Open", "", names(x)[1]), ".csv"))
    })

# the data can be found in the folder (execute the function!!!)
getwd()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I am looking to loop through my CSV and download the data from all the hundreds of tickers in my CSV.

Comment: How does your CSV look like? ... A small example would be helpful. You should be able to extract the ticker names from the CSV. Than you can download the data same as above (you don´t need a loop, R is vectorized). After that you simply need a function to write CSV´s eg. `write.table`

Comment: It is structured as SYMBOL NAME. For example, if I do ticker <- companyList[1:5, 'Symbol'] then print ticker, it shows all the first 5 company tickers. I want to pass this variable into getSymbols, but your example code is not working for me. I do nto want to type the tickers out manually.

Comment: I´ m not sure about that, but try `ticker <- unlist(companyList[1:5, 'Symbol'])`

Comment: Thanks! Its still not working, so I guess I will bite the bullet and type them out manually. Your intial post works but I wanted to avoid typing hundreds of tickers out. I really appreciate your post!!

Comment: One last suggestion.... try `ticker <- as.vector(companyList[1:5, 'Symbol'])` or `ticker <- as.vector(as.character(companyList[1:5, 'Symbol'))`

Comment: That worked!! But the only problem is that now when I do getSymbols(ticker) it loads the data, but when I next execute ticker[1] it just shows the company ticker instead of the data. I might just make another question. But Thank you for the answer, im one step closer to finishing this project ha.

Comment: Look at my example from above... or the link. It is usually to load them into an so called environment.... Than you can index your stocks by `$`